# What skills will I need to learn for a 'Security Analyst' job role?

Tags: network, defense, incident-analysis

What skills will I need to learn for a 'Security Analyst' job role?

By this, I mean someone who monitors the network to uncover compromised systems.

I believe this is similar to working in a Blue Team.

Comment: The term "Security Analyst" is *extremely* broad and can cover a vast array of responsibilities, skills, and experience levels. It's the infosec equivalent of saying "I work with computers". What I think you are asking about is a "SOC Analyst". If you search for those job listings, you will get a sense of what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

The exact details of a particular analyst position are going to vary from job req to job req. The best thing you can do is look at what various positions are requiring as background knowledge and become proficient in these functional areas.

To get you started, here is a job for one of our analyst positions, I think it's a good primer to get you started.

> **Demonstrable Skills and Capabilities**
>
> - *Strong interpersonal, organizational, communication, and writing
>     skills*
>
>   - Being an Analyst means engaging with clients; meeting their
>       objectives and communicating the details associated with potential
>       threats is critical to success. You must be the expert in the room,
>       and able to communicate and support your recommendations.
> - *Independent investigative skills*
>
>   - The Analyst must be able to make sense of the
>       technical information at their disposal. This includes the capability
>       to investigate technical elements they might never have seen before.
>       While senior personnel are available to provide assistance it's up to
>       the Analyst to investigate the issue prior to escalation.
>
> **Required Technical Skills**
>
> - Working knowledge of the TCP/IP suite of protocols
> - Conceptual
>     knowledge of network and systems architecture
> - Network segmentation
>     (e.g., DMZ)
> - Intrusion Detection Systems
> - Web application architecture
> - Active Directory Solid understanding of how major application layer
>     protocols function (e.g., HTTP, SMTP, DNS)
> - Basic knowledge of categories of malware and how they function (e.g., rootkits, trojans, adware)
> - Conceptual understanding of vulnerabilities and attack vectors
>     such as: SQL Injection Brute force attacks Portscans Malware infection
>     vectors Phishing attacks Driveby/Redirection attacks
>
> **Optional Skills**
>
> Certifications are always a plus, but not required:
>
> - CISSP
> - GCIH
> - GCIA
> - GSEC
>
> Programming/Scripting (e.g., Perl, Python, Ruby) Network traffic
>   analysis skills Comfortable in multiple operating systems (Windows,
>   Linux, Unix, OSX)

Comment: Programming:how about java?

Comment: @FastSnail For what? Most tasks can be accomplished quickly and efficiently with scripting languages. Not saying it would hurt to have a bkg in other languages, but I wouldn't consider it more useful than basic scripting skills for an analyst position.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the specific role and what level the role is (level 1, level 2 etc).

An understanding of what a Security Operations Center (SOC) is and how it operates (if the role is based in a SOC), or how the security analyst role fits into the wider ICT role will be needed.

Some concepts and tools that almost all security analyst roles will require at minimum a basic knowledge of are;

- Security Event and Incident Management (SIEM)

  - Protective Monitoring, Log Analysis & Use case development
- Vulnerability Management
- IDS/IPS filter managment and use
- Firewall Monitoing
- AV endpoint management
- Incident Response

In addition to this, understanding basic computing concepts, TCP/IP and security fundamentals will be essential.

Comment: What is the difference between those levels ? and what tasks likely each level analyst would be doing ?

Comment: There is a lot of crossover between the two, level 2 analysts will typically be slightly more experienced and act as a tier of escalation for any potential security incidents. For example, a level 1 analysis may monitor a live SEIM channel for any potential security incidents and filter out any false positives before raising them to a level 2 analysts for further investigation.
In an addition, a level 2 analysts may have more responsibility such as reporting to higher ups and quality checking the work of the level 1s. Again this will depend on the role.